# OneToMany mapping from Table to Foreign Table [Symfony 2 / Doctrine]

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

From what I've gathered, Symfony 2 / Doctrine uses the database definitions (foreign key constraints in my case) to map relations between entities. I have two tables in particular that I want to be able to relate from both sides, but I do not want to create redundant foreign keys in each table. In this case, I have an `Account` table, and a `Transaction` table.

**Account Table**

```
CREATE TABLE "account" (
    "account_id"            BIGSERIAL NOT NULL,
    "name"                  VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    "date_created"          TIMESTAMP (6) WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
    "date_modified"         TIMESTAMP (6) WITH TIME ZONE,

    CONSTRAINT "pk-account-account_id"
        PRIMARY KEY ("account_id"),
);
```

**Transaction Table**

```
CREATE TABLE "transaction" (
    "transaction_id"        BIGSERIAL NOT NULL,
    "account_id"            BIGINT NOT NULL,
    "amount"                MONEY NOT NULL,
    "date_created"          TIMESTAMP (6) WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
    "date_modified"         TIMESTAMP (6) WITH TIME ZONE,

    CONSTRAINT "pk-transaction-transaction_id"
        PRIMARY KEY ("transaction_id"),

    CONSTRAINT "fk-transaction-account_id-account-account_id"
        FOREIGN KEY ("account_id")
        REFERENCES "account" ("account_id")
            ON DELETE RESTRICT
            ON UPDATE CASCADE,
);
```

When I generate the entities using `php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities` I see that the transaction entity has an $account property, but my account entity does not have a $transaction entity. I assume this is because I do not define a foreign key constraint in my account table.

In my code, I create my account object by the following:

```
$accounts = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('BalancesBundle:Account')
        ->findAll();
```

I then would want to iterate over the array to get the total balance for each account. In the long-term, I'd like to create a helper method inside my account entity that would call `getTransactions()` to add up all of the transactions into one sum total.

Is this possible? I feel like I'm missing something, and that my only recourse would be to do this from within the transaction entity. I would like to avoid doing this from the transaction entity if possible.

Comment: Just a note: Doctrine doesn't use DB to map relations. It uses mappings. Also `doctrine:generate:entities` doesn't generate entities from DB, but from mappings, so I assume you have created them first. Since you started with sql tables, I assume that you used `doctrine:mapping:import` command. If you want to have bidirectional relation you should modify your mappings, not DB. Actually you should work with mappings and not DB.

Comment: You are right, I created the tables first and then used import. At the time I was unaware that Doctrine could generate the necessary SQL for me. I probably will be going that route from here on out. Thanks for the head's up.

Answer (score 1):

From what I get, you can't get transaction entities of the account entity. The weird thing is that you don't have "transactions" property inside your ccount entity, am I right ? Seems like a bad mapping.

Take a look at [Doctrine documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional), you have to define your "transcations" property inside your "account" entity and map it with the OneToMany association.

Then you can use "php bin/console do:ge:entities AppBundle:Account"

Comment: This answer, along with the comment from @dragoste, got me the total (pun intended) solution. I added the transaction property to my Account entity, along with the OneToMany annotation, updated my Transaction entity with the needed "inversedBy", then I had to edit my Account mapping to add the oneToMany definition, re-ran the generate:entities, and viola, it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If your entities are setup correctly then you should be able to access the transactions from the account.

```
foreach ($accounts as $account) {
   $transactions = $account->getTransactions();

   $transaction_total = 0;

   foreach($transactions as $transaction) {
      $transaction_total += $transaction->getAmount();
   }

   echo 'Transactions Total: '.$transaction_total;
}
```